# storing annotations as XML

Tags: php, xml, pdf, annotations

I have a javascript which adds annotations to PDF file on a website.
Now I want to store the PDF and annotations separately. When i open the PDF it should load with out annotations but on click of a button annotations should be displayed.
That means annotations should be loaded seperately. How to do it using XML.

Comment: Are you searching for an existing tool to do that? Or do you want to program a little tool for that and wonder where to start? In the latter case, which is your programming environment? Java? .Net? Something else?

Comment: I want to program a little tool. I want to use PHP. My question is how to store the data about annotations(ex:say the position of the highlighted text in canvas) using XML.

Comment: I added the [php] tag to your question. Hopefully your question now is found by people knowing their way around in PHP and PDF.